# How to replace letters with numbers in c++?

Tags: c++

Let's consider a word too long, if its length is strictly more than 10 characters. All too long words should be replaced with a special abbreviation.

This abbreviation is made like this: we write down the first and the last letter of a word and between them we write the number of letters between the first and the last letters. That number is in decimal system and doesn't contain any leading zeroes.

E.g, "localization" will be spelled as "l10n", and "internationalization» will be spelled as "i18n. 

 Input: 
 
localization 
internationalization 
Output:
 l10n 
i18n

Comment: Downvoters explain please?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because "questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string s;
while (std::cin >> s)
    std::cout << s.at(0) << s.length() - 2 << s.at(s.length() - 1) << "\n";
```

Comment: string::front and string::back showed up in C++11. `s[0]`, there isn't much you can do to simplify that, but `s[s.length() - 1]` collapses nicely into `s.back()`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your review(new skills get: )

Comment: I am of the opinion that Sam's edit is worse. Braces were removed, making it easier to inject errors and `at` is only useful here in the event of an empty string, impossible with `>>`

Comment: Because there is no risk of out of range so `at` is redundant?

Comment: My main beef is with the removal of the braces.

Comment: Indeed we hold the same taste(to me, brace is a must, nerve redundant, but braces may not be so important for online judge)

Comment: I've debugged and code reviewed way too much code where someone inserted a line with the correct indentation and didn't realize whoever had written the original code had left out the braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    while(getline(cin, str)) {
        if(str.length() == 0)
            break;
        if(str.length() >= 10)
            cout << str[0] << str.length() - 2 << str[str.length() - 1] << endl;
        else
            cout << str << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```